# Creating a centric REST API for a mobile and website application

Tags: php, python, rest, authentication

My next project requires me to develop both a mobile and a website application. To avoid duplicating code, I'm thinking about creating an API that both of these applications would use.

My questions regarding this are:

1. Is this approach sensible?
2. Are there any frameworks to help me with this?
3. How would I handle authentication?
4. Does this have an affect on scalability?

Comment: I've seen many people use [Slim Framework to create a RESTful API](http://www.9lessons.info/2014/12/create-restful-services-using-slim-php.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your questions are  -

1. Yes possible and in fact it makes perfect sense to me.
2. Yep. I am currently using `django` for Web and `djano-rest-framework` for REST API. Both are in same project and they share the same `model` and `querysets`. Web url is normal and API url starts with `/api`
3. For web I use normal Session based Authentication, for REST API I use token authentication
4. So far no. Both the web and api works perfectly for me. Deployed in 3 production environment.

links -

[django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

[django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually I doesn't make great sense. From my experience I know that mobile apps and web pages even if use the same backend very often require completely different set of data, and - (I know premature optimization is the root of all evil) - number of calls should be minimized for mobile applications to make them running smoothly. I'd separate mobile API from classic REST API, even with prefixes, e.g. `/api/m/` and `/api/`.
2. There're really many frameworks in a number of technologies. E.g. spring, django-rest-framework, express.js. Whatever you like.
3. Token authentication will be the best choice. For both web and mobile. For REST in general.
4. It shouldn't be a matter for you now.